# BigQuery partition expiration for TIMESTAMP column based partition

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm trying to test partition expiration on a table where I have set TIMESTAMP column based partition. Problem is that the partition expiration does not seem to work.

Here is what I do:

1) Create table with TIMESTAMP column partition together with 60 seconds expiration time

```
bq mk --table --project_id cool_project-007 --time_partitioning_field ts --time_partitioning_expiration 60  --schema ts:TIMESTAMP,label_1:STRING  dataset_sample.sample_x
```

[image]

2) From other table where columns are the same types I select ALL and copy/append values to the newly created table sample_x

3) There I would expect that all records with ts (TIMESTAMP) older than 60 seconds will be deleted. But they are not!

[image]

Please, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like table expiration, partition expiration are done by a periodical background process, so table/partition doesn't expire immediately at the expiration time. They are deleted when scanned by the background process. Normally people set it to a couple months or at least a couple days so this small delay is not a problem.

The good news is that we have changed to filter out expired partitions from query results. It will be released in a week or two.

Comment: perfect - that makes sense. It would be great to mention this in the official doc, but after the new feature you mentioned is out, this problem should be a history :). Thanks!

Comment: Great to know but I am having an issue, I have a day expiration but my queries return the last two partitions of data? DAY (expirationMs: 86400000)

Comment: Can you post a job id so we can take a look?

Comment: @HuaZhang I know this is a bit old but I'm not able to find the feature you mentioned here: "The good news is that we have changed to filter out expired partitions from query results. It will be released in a week or two." - Is it available?

Comment: It's not a public feature. It's an internal implementation that has been rolled out in 2018.

Answer (score 0):

Great question - I think you and previous answer misinterpreted partition by TIMESTAMP column!
Even though it is TIMESTAMP column that is used for partitioning  - the partitioning itself is still by DAY -

> partition by timestamp_column — partitions the table using the date of the TIMESTAMP column

You can see more [`here`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/data-definition-language#partition_expression)

Which means that you shouldn't expect that all records with ts (TIMESTAMP) older than 60 seconds will be deleted.  Rather this should happen 60 seconds after the end of respective day

Comment: Good point. The expiration is on partitions, not on single records. So a record will only expire when the day partition it belongs to expires. My previous answer still holds in the sense that the day partition won't be deleted right at 60 seconds after the end of that day. Like even if you write to a day in last year it will only be deleted when scanned by the background process. Partition/table expiration is mainly for reducing storage cost by deleting old data. It's better to filter records explicitly in the query.

Comment: agree - it only holds "in the sense ..."  but overall I think it does not answer the specific OP's question :o)