# How can I force expired big query partitions to delete immediately?

Tags: google-bigquery

I see in https://stackoverflow.com/a/49105008/6191970 that partitions with an expiration that is expired still take some unknown amount of time to be deleted, though they are no longer are included in queries after expiration. I experimented with setting the partition expiration on a table which is partitioned hourly as so:

```
ALTER TABLE `my.table`
SET OPTIONS ( partition_expiration_days=.1 )
```

And was surprised that even after a few hours, setting the expiration back to its original limit of 90 days, all of the data was still there.

Is there any way to force deletion specifically of all expired partitions?
If not, what time frame is to be expected for this data to clear out?

This is a sensitive data security problem for my use case where we do not want old data to exist.

Answer (score 0):

BigQuery retains data for 7 days, officially it offers a time traveling feature as well. Count that in your Organization policy.

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/time-travel